# How to install php-pear to AWS EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, pear

I'm new to Amazon EC2.
I'm trying to install php-pear in my Amazon server.
But i got some error below like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMGIv.png)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check this link http://jafty.com/blog/installing-pear-on-amazon-ec2-or-ubuntu-linux-server/

Comment: Thanks, it work for me

Answer (score 1):

I just installed it earlier today on my EC2 Linux instance running PHP7 as follows:

```
sudo yum install php7-pear
```

Once installed:

```
pear install Mail
pear install Net_SMTP
```

However it was not piece of cake after that. I ran into other challenges related to SMTP settings related to PHP7 and Postfix, which gave some hard time for my specific case, since I wanted to send out base64 encoded image inline, which apparently is a very unusual case since I couldn't find any help at all for it. However, for a simple email sending out, all you need is the following code:

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "My Name <no-reply@example.com>";
$host = "smtp.example.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "user@example.com";
$password = "password";
$subject = "Some subject";
$headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
$body = "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$body .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$body .= "This is the message body.";
$body .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
            'debug' => true,
            'host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent! </p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have php installed, you can follow below steps

1. **Elevate Privileges**: This step is important for pear to be installed standard directory. If you skip this, pear will be installed in ec2-user directory and will be pretty much unusable due to a ton of ownership and permission issues.

   `sudo -i`
2. **Download and Install Pear**
   `wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
   php go-pear.phar`
3. **Install Mail and Net_SMTP Packages**

   `pear install Mail
   pear install Net_SMTP`

The installation will ask for updating the php.ini file. Please do that.